# making single function for array of pushbuttons in QT

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, oop, qt5

I'm new in QT. I have 35 push_buttons in an array. I want to write single function for this array of buttons. that function will only set string, different for each button. like "10,10" nextone like "15,15" etc.
I have seen signalmappers which i can able to understand.

give simple and easy idea.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 35;i++){
    PB << new QPushButton();
}

ui->setupUi(this);

PB[0]=ui->pB_00;PB[1]=ui->pB_01;PB[2]=ui->pB_02;PB[3]=ui->pB_03;
PB[4]=ui->pB_04;PB[5]=ui->pB_05;PB[6]=ui->pB_06;PB[7]=ui->pB_07;
PB[8]=ui->pB_08;PB[9]=ui->pB_09;PB[10]=ui->pB_10;PB[11]=ui->pB_11;
PB[12]=ui->pB_12;PB[13]=ui->pB_13;PB[14]=ui->pB_14;PB[15]=ui->pB_15;
PB[16]=ui->pB_16;PB[17]=ui->pB_17;PB[18]=ui->pB_18;PB[19]=ui->pB_19;
PB[20]=ui->pB_20;PB[21]=ui->pB_21;PB[22]=ui->pB_22;PB[23]=ui->pB_23;
PB[24]=ui->pB_24;PB[25]=ui->pB_25;PB[26]=ui->pB_26;PB[27]=ui->pB_27;
PB[28]=ui->pB_28;PB[29]=ui->pB_29;PB[30]=ui->pB_30;PB[31]=ui->pB_31;
PB[32]=ui->pB_32;PB[33]=ui->pB_33;PB[34]=ui->pB_34;
```

Comment: please use code block instead of inline code

Comment: Do you just want to map existing `ui->` buttons to an array?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a function that only takes two parameters. The first parameter would be which button to access. The next one would be the text to set.
Example:

```
void Parent::changeText(int button, QString text)
{
    PB[button].setText(text);
}
```

You can cycle through to do multiple buttons.

Answer (score 0):

If the buttons already exist in your `ui` element, your current loop does not need to create `new` QPushButtons. Instead of using designer to insert your buttons you can do it in code.

```
// Your button array, this is likely a private member in your class.
QList< QPushButton* > PB;

for( auto i = 0; i < 35; ++i )
{
    // Create new button with textValue == "i" 
    auto button = new QPushButton{ QString::number( i ) };

    // Store in your list
    PB << button;

    // Add to ui
    ui->containerQWidget->layout()->addWidget( button );
}
```

Comment: but, how to set a single string variable having different values for each button with single function for all the button???

Comment: 1 string, 35 buttons? Or 35 strings and 35 buttons?

Comment: I mean that user have to select(click) one button. on push button clicked a string variable is set to points(location of button like 10,10 etc) different for each button. i have to store one value at a time. the point(string) should be different for each button. - @laser_wizard

Comment: Ahhhh... Do you need to display the text on the button? Or only store it in the variable associated with the button?

Comment: need to store in SQLite database but not using these buttons. it will be stored using save button.

Comment: Just to be clear, you need to sore the pixel location (x,y) when a user clicks a button?